# What is the fastest way to copy a QImage's pixels to an array?

Tags: c++, qt, opencl

I'm planning to store an [QImage](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qimage.html)'s pixel data in an array, then do some work with it in OpenCL.

What is the best approach to get all pixel data (colour code)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

uchar * QImage::bits () gives the pointer to the first pixel data. You can create an OpenCL buffer with CL_MEM_USE_HOST_POINTER flag by passing pointer returned from bits.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `QImage::bits()` and `QImage::byteCount()` methods to get a raw pointer to the image data and the size in bytes of the image data.